# Pandas DataFrame add column by two columns from other DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm studying Data Science with Python Pandas.
But, I'm not good at handling data.
So, I need some help.

df1

```
>>> df1
    stamp  id  col1  col2
0  100000   1   100    60
1  100000   2   100    30
2  100001   1    10    10
3  100001   1    20    30
4  100001   2    20    10
5  100001   2    20    90
6  100001   3    30    10
7  100002   1   300    30
8  100002   4    40    60
```

df2

```
>>> df2
    start     end  id  val
0  100000  100001   1    1
1  100002  100003   4    1
```

Using python3 pandas dataframe,
How do I add a new column to the data that has the same 'id' value and 'stamp' values between 'start' and 'end' values?

@ Want to make result like this

```
>>> result
    stamp  id  col1  col2  val
0  100000   1   100    60    1
1  100000   2   100    30    0
2  100001   1    10    10    1
3  100001   1    20    30    1
4  100001   2    20    10    0
5  100001   2    20    90    0
6  100001   3    30    10    0
7  100002   1   300    30    0
8  100002   4    40    60    1
```

How can i make it?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
result = pd.DataFrame()

df2['stamp'] = df2['start']

result = pd.merge(df1,df2, on='stamp')
```

Comment: pd.merge(df1,df2, on='stamp') | pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['stamp', 'id'], how='left') ==> Both ways are not correct.

Answer (score 0):

[melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the second dataframe(df2), so that start and end columns are 'melted' into one column; then proceed to [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the new dataframe with `df1`, with `stamp` and `id` as the merge columns, and [fill the null values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with 0

```
df2 = df2.melt(["id", "val"], value_name="stamp")

df1.merge(df2.drop("variable", axis=1), on=["stamp", "id"], how="left").fillna(0)


stamp   id  col1    col2    val
0   100000  1   100 60  1.0
1   100000  2   100 30  0.0
2   100001  1   10  10  1.0
3   100001  1   20  30  1.0
4   100001  2   20  10  0.0
5   100001  2   20  90  0.0
6   100001  3   30  10  0.0
7   100002  1   300 30  0.0
8   100002  4   40  60  1.0
```